# How to deploy a single web application(nodejs+reactjs) on two EC2 server for load balancing and autoscaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, aws-auto-scaling

My client is asking me to deploy web application (nodejs backend+reactjs frontend) on two EC2 servers. Inorder to achieve good load balancing and autoscaling based on traffic,
Note: client doesn't want to go for single server of high version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of achieving a satisfying architecture for this problem. If we are looking into using EC2 instances we can do the following:

Deploy your back-end into Target Group for an [Auto Scaling Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html) and put an Application Load Balancer in front of it. Instances can automatically register to the load balancer, which can distribute traffic between them.

Deploy your static front-end application into an [S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html), if necessary, use a CloudFront distribution for caching and faster loads.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the front-end is a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (browser-generated HTML), then host the React part on S3 + CloudFront

Regarding deploying Node on EC2:

Use [CloudFormation](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudformation-user-guide/blob/main/doc_source/example-templates-autoscaling.md) to setup the infrastructure (the EC2 machines, ASG, and Load Balancer)

Then use CodeDeploy to deploy / update the application

Here is a post on deploying Node.js using CodeDeploy: https://hub.packtpub.com/deploy-nodejs-apps-aws-code-deploy/

You might find it easier to use [Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html) though

Comment: Client wants to deploy react part on the same server

Comment: @SyedAbubakr ok, skip the first paragraph then :)